# Why does PyLong_AsUnsignedLongLong function fail to convert a numpy.uint64 element, whereas PyLong_AsLongLong succeeds?

Tags: python, c, numpy, python-c-api

I'm working on a C-extension for Python which implements a method that converts a list of *numpy* elements (`numpy.uint64` in this case) to the `unsigned long long` *C-type* (using the `PyLong_AsUnsignedLongLong` function). The elements of the list are then summed up and the resulting sum is returned to the Python layer.

To create the module I wrote this code in `testmodule.c`:

```
#include <Python.h>

static PyObject *method_sum_list_u64(PyObject *self, PyObject *args);

static PyMethodDef testmoduleMethods[] = {
    {"sum_list_u64", method_sum_list_u64, METH_VARARGS, "docs"},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

static struct PyModuleDef testmodule = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "testmodule",
    "docs",
    -1,
    testmoduleMethods
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_testmodule(void) {
    return PyModule_Create(&testmodule);
}
```

And here is my method:

```
static PyObject *method_print_list_u64(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
    uint64_t sum = 0;
    PyObject *input_list;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O!", &PyList_Type, &input_list))
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    Py_ssize_t data_points = PyList_Size(input_list);

    for (Py_ssize_t i = 0; i < data_points; i++)
    {
        PyObject *item = PyList_GetItem(input_list, i);
        sum += PyLong_AsUnsignedLongLong(item);
    }

    return PyLong_FromUnsignedLongLong(sum);
}
```

My `setup.py` file:

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension

def main():
    setup(name="testmodule",
          version="1.0.1",
          description="Python interface for the testmodule C library function",
          ext_modules=[Extension("testmodule", ["testmodule.c"])])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And a simple test script called `mytest.py`:

```
import numpy as np
import testmodule

input_list = [np.uint64(1000)]
print(testmodule.sum_list_u64(input_list))
```

To reproduce the error I run:

```
$ python setup.py install
$ python mytest.py
TypeError: an integer is required

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mytest.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(testmodule.sum_list_u64(input_list))
SystemError: <built-in function sum_list_u64> returned a result with an error set
```

Now, if I replace `PyLong_AsUnsignedLongLong` with `PyLong_AsLongLong` everything works fine. Why does `PyLong_AsUnsignedLongLong` fail and `PyLong_AsLongLong` doesn't?

Comment: It might be an idea to [look carefully at the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html) - the functions differ in what they do if they aren't passed the exact correct type. Also `isinstance(numpy.uint64(5),int)`

Comment: @DavidW You're right, the functions differ, but I can't figure out why they don't behave similarly since they are of the same class. At this point I'm OK with implementing a workaround but I'm not sure what the best solution is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isinstance(numpy.uint64(5),int)` returns `False` - Numpy scalar integer types are not subclasses of the Python integer type. They have different internal structures and so will not work with a C API function expecting a Python integer (notably, the Python integer type can handle an arbitrarily large integer while the Numpy types are limited to the size of the C type used internally).

If you read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html) you see that `PyLong_AsLongLong` will attempt a conversion to a Python int, and `PyLong_AsUnsignedLongLong` will only accept an instance of instance of `PyLongObject`. I don't know why that is and I don't think it would be easy to find out. However, it is the documented behaviour and it explains what you're seeing.

A few options:

- Convert everything to Python `PyLongObject` first. This method is probably the most robust (it'll accept any sensible data type you pass into it), but does involve creating intermediate Python objects (remember to `DECREF` them when you're done with them). Use `PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(PyLongObject, item, NULL)` (although other options may be available too). You can then use `PyLong_AsUnsignedLongLong` since you now definitely have the correct type.
- If you're always passing Numpy scalar types then use the Numpy function [PyArray_ScalarAsCtype](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html#c.PyArray_ScalarAsCtype) to get the data from that quickly and directly. You *will* want some error and type checking to make sure that you have actually received a `numpy.uint64`.
- Consider passing a Numpy array rather than a list of `numpy.uint64`. It isn't clearly what you're getting from using isolated Numpy scalar types, while an array is stored internally as C array of `uint64_t` that you could quickly iterate over.
- Consider dropping the `numpy.uint64`s and just using plain Python `int`s in your list since I don't see what you gain from using the Numpy type. Then you could call `PyLong_AsUnsignedLongLong`.

---

You're also missing *all* error checking in your function. Most C API calls have a return value that indicates an error (usually `NULL` but sometimes different). Checking for this is important. Do not skip it!